# win10 batch write newline in file

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, echo, newline

I want to write some text in the file File.txt, and it works using `echo (text) > File.txt`, but how can I make a new line? if I use another echo command, like this:
`echo (text1) > File.txt`
`echo (text2) > File.txt`
it overrides the existing text, but I want it to write the text to a new line

The Output should look something like this:

1: Text1
2: Text2
3:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do double redirect `>>` which means it will append to file:

```
(echo text1)>file.txt
(echo text2)>>file.txt
```

or even better, do everything in a parenthesized block, and redirect to file:

```
@(echo text1
 echo text2
)>File.txt
```

Note, the above is going to recreate the file each time it runs, but echo everything inside the parenthesis to the file.

If you have variables that needs to be logged without recreating the file each time, again use `>>`:

```
@(echo text1
 echo text2
)>>File.txt
```